# Which is greater as $n$ gets larger, $f(n)=2^{2^{2^n}}$ or $g(n)=100^{100^n}$?

Tags: asymptotics, problem-solving

It is the first time I met such a question:

> Which is greater as $n$ gets larger, $f(n)=2^{2^{2^n}}$ or $g(n)=100^{100^n}$?

Intuitively I think $f(n)$ would gradually become larger as $n$ gets larger, but I find it hard to produce an argument.
Is there any trick to use for this type of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare $f(n)$ with $G(n)=256^{256^n}>g(n)$. You arrive at
$G(n) = 2^{2^{8n+3}}$, so you just need to compare $2^n$ vs. $8n+3$.

Comment: I find this method ingenious,thank you! Is this a general method? By finding a number bigger than one yet smaller than another to act as an intermediate? Do you know where I can find similar questions and methods of solving them?

Comment: Whenever you see more than two expressions chained together with $<$ or $\leq$, then you have encountered intermediates. (Same for $>$ and $\geq$ of course.) So I think it's a ubiquitous method... and you already suspected that $f$ would win, despite the $100$, so this suggests that we can afford to increase the $100$ just to make comparison easier. I considered $128=2^7$ first, but $7$ in the next exponent would have to be scaled up again, so I settled on $2^8$.

Answer (score 2):

Take logs

$$\log\log\log(f)=\log\log\log(2^{2^{2^n}})=n\log(2\log(2\log(2)))$$
$$\log\log(g)=\log\log(100^{100^n})=n\log (100(\log (100)))$$

Which are both linear and grow at the same rate, so to say. Now exponentiate to retrieve $f,g$.

Comment: you should mention that log is monotonic.

Comment: @JonathanAronson You just did! :)

Comment: Sorry I did not get it... Could you explain in more detail?

Answer (score -1):

Try taking the logs. Log is a monotonic transformation.